# Java package run-time error

Tags: java, package

I am newbie in java. I am running java programs via Ubuntu terminal 
I just started java package topic and have been dealing with a problem for several hours.
I tried to create a simple package called pack which has single class Hello.
I created a directory pack. Inside the pack I put Hello.class file intp pack directory via

```
javac -d ./pack Hello.java
```

command.
Then I included pack package into a class containing main method. The class's name is test and it is located in test.java file This class is located in another directory. I compile via

```
javac -cp ./pack test.java
```

It compiles without any error and everything is ok.
However, when I enter command

```
java -cp ./pack test
```

it gives me

```
Error: Could not find or load main class test
```

When I tried

```
java test
```

command. The following message showed up

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pack/Hello
at test.main(test.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pack.Hello
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 1 more
```

Can anybody explain me what I am doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Sorry, I did bot include my source codes. Here they are.

```
import pack.Hello;
public class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Hello.HelloMessage();
    }
}
```

This is test.java file which tests if everything is ok. It is located at

```
/home/uesername/apps
```

directory.

Then I created "pack" directory. Full path to the pack directory is

```
home/username/apps/pack
```

Inside the "pack" I put Hello.java file. The content of Hello.java file is

```
package pack;
public class Hello
{
    public static void HelloMessage()
    {
        System.out.println("hello, world");
    }
}
```

Comment: " I created a directory pack. Inside the pack I put Hello.class file intp pack ". `-d` flag creates the package structure for you don't do it yourself

Comment: Can you show the source code. We need at least (from test.java) the line that starts with "package" and the line that "import"s Hello. And from Hello.java we need the line that starts with "package".

Answer (score 2):

To begin with I suggest you use an IDE to setup you environment for compiling, running and debugging.

The problem you have is that you have compiled with the wrong path.

```
javac -cp . pack/Hello.java
javac -cp . pack/test.java
```

and

```
java -cp . pack.Hello
```

or

```
java -cp . pack.test
```

The problem is that you compiled a class with package `pack` in a directory `pack` and you would end up with

```
pack/pack/Hello.class
```

I suggest you check where the Hello.class file has been placed.

Comment: You are right. Hello.class file is in pack/pack directory. I copied it into pack directory. But when I enter java command it still gives me error messages

Comment: @olzhabala which is why I suggest using an IDE which will setup the directories for you, compile and run the code and make it easier to debug it too. I use IntelliJ Community Edition.